# How to make password and mobile number validation in android?

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which I have three fields and I want to put some validation for email and password ...condition is that

1. Mobile number should be beeen 7 to 15 digit
2. Password length should be 4 to 8 doesn't matter numeric or character.

How can I do that.

here is my code:-

```
private boolean isValidPassword(String pass) {
    if (pass != null && pass.length() >=4) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
if (!isValidEmail(m_Email)|| !isValidPassword(m_Password)){
        m_EmailEditText.setError("Invalid email");
        m_PasswordEditText.setError("Password must be between 4 to 8 characters long");
}
```

and don't have code for mobile number

Comment: You need to use some regex to check the String, the regex will test the length AND the character accepted. You need to specifiy a pattern for the phone number, to accept specific splitter or anyting. For email it's easier since this is a standard.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private boolean validation(String password, String number, String emailiId) {
        if (password.length() >= 4 && password.length() <= 8) {
            if (number.length() >= 7 && password.length() <= 15) {
                if (isValidEmail(emailiId)) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    m_emailEdittext.setError("Invalid EmailID");
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                m_numberEdittext.setError("number must be between 7 to 51 characters long");
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            m_passwordEdittext.setError("password must be between 4 to 8 characters long");
            return false;
        }
    }


    private void executeURL(){
        if(validation(m_passwordEdittext.getText().toString(),m_numberEdittext.getText().toString(),m_emailEdittext.getText().toString())){
            // code to execute URL
        }
    }
```

Comment: and how to make condition for if all condition match then execute url if not then show error

Comment: its works on when I enter numeric digit of mentioned condition .....but when I enter mix numeric and alpahbetic it doies not show error

Comment: In password field?

Comment: I have to set all three field in dataModel class and then execute like this

Comment: s_m_oRegisterStorage = new CRegistrationDataStorage();// creation object of registrationData storage
      s_m_oRegisterStorage.setM_szMobileNumber(m_MobileNumber);// get mobile number from mobile number editText
      s_m_oRegisterStorage.setPin(m_Password);// get password from password editText
      s_m_oRegisterStorage.setM_szEmailId(m_Email);// get email  from email editText

      // excecuting url
      new CRegisterUser().execute(s_szReg_url);

Comment: Can you please this in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

For email

```
    private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
        return email.length() >=7 && email.length() <=15;
    }
```

For password:

```
private boolean isValidPassword(String number) {
    return number.length() >=4 && number.length()<=8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this code may be help you

```
// your submit button clicklistner
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            final String email = emailEditText.getText().toString();
            if (!isValidEmail(email) {
                emailEditText.setError("Invalid Email");
            }

            final String pass = passEditText.getText().toString();
            if (!isValidPassword(pass)) {
                passEditText.setError("Invalid Password");
            }

        }
    });
}
 /* for Email validation*/

private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
    String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();
}

   /* your password validation*/
private boolean isValidPassword(String pass) {
    if (pass != null ||  password.length() >= 4 && password.length() <= 8) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```